# How to draw a histogram with broken x-axis and string labels?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am trying to draw a histogram with broken x-axis. I learnt the basic solution from this [post](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/broken-axes-graph-in-gnuplot-3.html).

However, the x-axis of my histogram is based on strings, not number. It's like this:

```
set terminal pdf
set output "test-bar.pdf"
set boxwidth 1.0 absolute
set style fill solid 1 border 0
set datafile separator ','
set style data histograms
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45
set ylabel 'Normalized Overhead (%)'
set grid ytics
set yrange [0:10]
plot 'test-bar.csv' using 2:xtic(1) lc rgb "#1E90FF"  title ''
```

And the data is listed like this:

```
expand , 8.63390441828
cut , 6.84657194596
sync , 6.03615235627
fold , 4.22117995557
nl , 3.54228486647
truncate , 2.66222961714
tr , 2.38357169059
stty , 2.28166797757
users , 2.04211869831
factor , 1.81517270821
tac , 1.790947574
uniq , 1.78799489138
mv , 1.75054704603
mktemp , 1.72228202368
dircolors , 1.6974169738
```

Right now the plot is in this way:

[image]

If I want to leverage the `broken axis` feature, say, insert the broken between `stty` and `users`, how can I do that?

Am I clear enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you use xtic labels from your data file, the xtics are placed at integer x-values, starting at `0`. Now, you cannot directly set arbitrary x-values when plotting histograms. You must use `newhistogram at ...` to shift the second part of the histogram further to the right:

```
split = 8
plot 'test-bar.csv' using 2:xtic(1) every ::0::(split-1) lt 1,\
     newhistogram at split+1,\
     '' using 2:xtic(1) every ::split lt 1
```

Drawing of the upper and lower borders as well as the broken axis signs is done as shown in the post you linked. A possible full script could be

```
set terminal pdf
set output "test-bar.pdf"
set boxwidth 0.5 absolute
set style fill solid 1 border 0
set datafile separator ','
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45
set ylabel 'Normalized Overhead (%)'
set grid ytics
set yrange [0:10]

unset key
set border 2+8
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#1E90FF"

split=8
dx = 0.125
dy = 0.03

do for [i=0:1] {
  set arrow 1+i from graph 0,graph i to first split-dx,graph i lt -1 nohead
  set arrow 3+i from first split+dx,graph i to graph 1,graph i lt -1 nohead

  set arrow 5+i from first split-2*dx,graph i-dy to first split,graph i+dy lt -1 nohead
  set arrow 7+i from first split,graph i-dy to split+2*dx,graph i+dy lt -1 nohead
}

plot 'test-bar.csv' using 2:xtic(1) every ::0::(split-1) lt 1,\
     newhistogram at split+1,\
     '' using 2:xtic(1) every ::split lt 1
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't add or stack more columns, you could use the `boxes` plotting style, which allows you to use a normal numerical axis.